# How to use the Keycloak rest-api to create a user with a default role using client credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I've got a Keycloak instance setup as a local docker container, where I don't want users to use the Keycloak UI to register themselves, instead I require the users to use an ASP.NET (6) WebApi endpoint that can be used to register users in Keycloak.

I've created a **client** that has currently got the **service account role**: '**manage-users**'.

In my Api project I've exposed an endpoint '**api/register**' that would make a HTTP POST request to '**{keycloakUrl}/admin/realms/{realm}/users**' that allows me to create a user.

How do I go about assigning a role '**customer**' to the users registered via the '**api/register**' endpoint?

Furthermore; how do I limit the clients permission to only be able to create an account instead of having all the management permissions set by the 'manage-users' role?

[image: Service Account Role Setup]